# Firestore: How to avoid sync order issue while using updatedAt timestamp to reduce reads?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have collection called `tasks` and each document contains fields like

```
updatedAt
name
isDone
```

Instead of querying all docs all the time, I get the latest `updatedAt` from cache and build the query using  `greaterThan:latestUpdatedAt`. But I feel this logic can horribly go wrong in this scenario.
Consider a user using this app from his phone and web also.

- Let's consider current `updatedAT` on user's phone is `2023-5-20 08:01:00`
- User creates task `T1` on `web` which immediately synced to server with `updatedAt` being `2023-5-20 09:01:00`
- User creates a task `T2` on phone but at the moment phone has no internet connection
- When user gets connection back on his phone `T2` will sync to server with `updatedAt` being `2023-5-20 09:02:00`

Now the problem is I have no idea how the firestore internal sync logic works so if sync of `T2` happens before get tasks query `greaterThan:latestUpdatedAt` then my `latestUpdatedAt` becomes `2023-5-20 09:02:00` and I will never get task `T1` which is created on web. This is just a speculation and I am not sure about but without the confirmation I am bit skeptical to push the app to production.

This idea of reducing reads is inspired by an [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e) written by firebase expert [Alex Mamo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5246885/alex-mamo) but I am not sure whether he is aware of this issue or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update `latestUpdatedAt` when you GET data and not when you PUSH data to Firebase.

You need a local date to save the last sync and a remote one to track updates, when the remote date is after the local date you have to fetch data from the server and update your local date with the new one.

with this approach, your scenario is:

- `localUpdateAt` on the phone is `2023-5-20 08:01:00` and `remoteUpdateAt` is `2023-5-20 08:01:00`
- User creates task `T1` on the web which immediately synced to the server with `remoteUpdatedAt` being `2023-5-20 09:01:00`
- User creates a task `T2` on the phone but at the moment phone has no internet connection
- When the user gets connection back on his phone `T2` will sync to the server with `remoteUpdatedAt` being `2023-5-20 09:02:00`
- At this time the mobile app tries to get new data from the server, your `localUpdateAt` on the phone is still `2023-5-20 08:01:00` that is before `remoteUpdatedAt` get data from the server with `greaterThan:localUpdateAt`

Usually, I create a collection specific to store the last updates for others' collections.

I hope can be helpful for you.

Comment: When firestore syncs data to server it also updates cache(which is not in my control) which in turn changes my lastUpdatedAt value.

Comment: I store localUpdateAt on shared pref

Comment: How do you get /update localUpdateAt?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: How do you fetch` localUpdateAt` ?

Comment: You can get it from shared preferences or you can get the last last update from your items. There are many approaches

Comment: Even if you store in sharedpref you have to read it from firestore only. It will still won't work

Answer (score 0):

How about saving `lastSyncTime` to local [SharePreference](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) only if the connection state of the Firebase is online?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state

Scenario:

0. [2023-5-20 07:01:00][phone][online]: phone `lastSyncTime`=2023-5-20 07:01:00
1. [2023-5-20 09:01:00][web][online]: web SharePref=09:01:00, same as **T1**'s `updateAt`
2. [2023-5-20 09:02:00][phone][offline]: phone `lastSyncTime` no change, **T2**'s `updateAt` is not enable because server is offline
3. [2023-5-20 09:03:00][phone][online]: **check all documents after 2023-5-20 07:01:00**, update phone`lastSyncTime`=2023-5-20 09:03:00, same as **T2**'s `updateAt`

Comment: There is no guarantee that firestore should be connected when real-time database is online, so this logic will also have edge case

Comment: OK. Maybe you can  get more ideas from the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDvdAFP6OhQ&ab_channel=Firebase

Comment: I do understand how firestore offline support works but that video does not answer this -"When there is a pending write and fresh docs to read created on another device  then what is the order of operation"

Comment: Let's say I am offline and created a task and my `updatedAt` of last synced task is 8:00PM. Meanwhile I created  another task from web app which get's `updatedAt` time 8:01PM. At 8.02 my mobile goes online and now firestore completes pending writes and immediately closes the app. When he opens again last updated at will be 8.02PM and I wll never get task created on web at 8.01PM

Comment: You can check the video at [5:50](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDvdAFP6OhQ&t=350s). He said the firebase simply goes with a strategy with the last write it receives wins. Synchronizing the same document between different devices may always be unpredictable.

Comment: In that video he talks about conflict resolution(he is writing to same to doc), but my question not about that.